# Google Map View is leaking very much

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks

I've previously used the MapFragment, but it was slow for my needs. The MapView is almost instantly and fits my needs exactly. But there is one thing they both have in common:

Huge memory leaking.
I've 'destroyed' the MapView like I should when exiting the activity and it still leaks. The MapView is in an activity that is frequently opened and closed and opened quickly again. Could that be the issue?

Here are some screeenshots of my hprof files (I'd rather not upload the hprof files, due to possible sensitive information):

[image: The leaking of the Google Maps API]
[image: The leaking of the Google Maps API #2]

I've had multiple leaks, and they al point to the same classes.

However, I am using a custom class, which is unneeded at this moment, and I'll revert back to the default MapView.

Comment: You should reuse your MapView, not keep recreating one.

Comment: How? The MapView is in the activity layout, should I use mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState) in my onCreate method?

Comment: Gotcha, did a bit of looking into this since it seems interesting. There are a few bugs reported about leaks with MapView (for example https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8111 ). It looks like it could be a bug if you are in fact handling the view appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that's the case, but I did something stupid using Kotlin.
Kotlin got null-safety.

```
googleMapView?.onDestroy()
```

I called that in `onDestroy()` of my Fragment. Guess what? googleMapView was null, that's why it didn't call it's `onDestroy()`! Wasted around 2 hours on this, because I thought some of my custom classes kept references or other things that led to this...